# Detecting touch events on controls within UIPageViewController in Monotouch

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, uigesturerecognizer, uipageviewcontroller

I have several buttons positioned on my ViewController within the area covered by the `UIPageViewController`'s `GestureRecognizers`. Taps in this area are consumed by the `UIPageViewController` and never reach the buttons below.

I've read [iPad - PageViewController - Show next view controller on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7916251/ipad-pageviewcontroller-show-next-view-controller-on-button-click) and [UIPageViewController Gesture recognizers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788780/uipageviewcontroller-gesture-recognizers) and understand the principle but have no prior Obj-C experience and am struggling to recreate these solutions in C#.

Could somebody please provide an example of how this is done in MonoTouch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how your first link would translate into C# using MonoTouch (note: untried).

First you would create your own (non .NET) *delegate* for `UIGestureRecognizer` like this:

```
class MyUIGestureRecognizerDelegate : UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    public override bool ShouldReceiveTouch (UIGestureRecognizer recognizer, UITouch touch)
    {
        return (!(touch.View is UIControl));
    }
}
```

It will return `true` to if the touch gesture does not apply to a `UIControl` (including buttons).

Then you need to assign this *delegate* to the `GestureRecognizers` that are assigned to your `UIPageViewController`.

```
MyUIGestureRecognizerDelegate del = new MyUIGestureRecognizerDelegate ();

UIPageViewController pvc = new UIPageViewController ();

foreach (var gr in pvc.GestureRecognizers)
    gr.Delegate = del;
```

This lets you adapt how the gesture will be interpreted. If not handled by the gesture itself then it should be routed to your own controls/buttons.