# How to add a button on UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, ipad, uipageviewcontroller

I have created an iPad app, using `UIPageviewController` in Xcode 4.2 (iOS 5). Now, I want to add a button, at the left-bottom corner of the page, which will appear on every page.

The problem is, while clicking the button, a page transition takes place, and the button click event is not called.

Comment: Xcode 4.3? Are you sure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take control over the Gesture Recognizers. Decide which one gets the click, take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8152294/454772)