# UIPageController in conjuction with UIPageControl?

Tags: ios, uipagecontrol

I have been using `UIPageController` to navigate between different controllers. Now I would like to add that dots at the bottom, so user can see on which controller he is at. That is achieved via `UIPageControl`. Is there easy way to combine those two?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From the bottom of UIPageViewController.h (iOS6+) ~

> A page indicator will be visible if both methods are implemented, transition style is 'UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll', and navigation orientation is 'UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal'.
>   Both methods are called in response to a 'setViewControllers:...' call, but the presentation  index is updated automatically in the case of gesture-driven navigation.

```
- (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0); // The number of items reflected in the page indicator.
- (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0); // The selected item reflected in the page indicator.
```

Otherwise, I think you need to add a `UIPageControl` to your `UIPageViewController` and basically tie them together to keep them in sync...but then you do have to do all the tying manually.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400870/uipageviewcontroller-return-the-current-visible-view is probably what you're looking for?

Answer (score 10):

If you are using Page Based application template of Xcode then go to
Attribute inspector and set  Transiton style property to Scroll.

and go to your application AppDelegate.m file and set the tint color for the

```
 UIPageControl *pageControl = [UIPageControl appearance];
    pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

For the page based Xcode template its already their for iOS 6,iOS 7 just its color is set to white.