# UIPageViewController not showing dots

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I'm using a UIPageViewController to show two views, but I'm not getting dots at the bottom.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{ 
    if(viewController == oneViewController) {
        self.navigationController.navigationItem.title=@"Options";
        return twoViewController;
    }
    else
    {
        self.navigationController.navigationItem.title=@"All Schedule";
        return oneViewController;
    }
} 

- (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return 2;
}
```

Comment: Actually i read,but iam nt getting please give exact method to show dots like(page control).Thanks in advance..

Comment: You need to update your question with the code you've tried so far. (We're not here to do all the work - you need to have at least attempted to solve this yourself after reading the relevant documentation.)

Comment: - (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if(viewController == oneViewController)
    {
        self.navigationController.navigationItem.title=@"Options";
        return twoViewController;
    }
    else
    {
        self.navigationController.navigationItem.title=@"All Schedule";
        return oneViewController;
    }


} and - (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return 2;
}

Comment: you need to used **PageControl** simply drag it to xib and make outlet and used it. If you haved used it from xib then see pageControlproperty and set number of pages here..

Answer (score 9):

You can do it using just a `UIPageViewController`, but it will only appear when you set the transition style to `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll`

Check out:
[this SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916216/uipagecontroller-in-conjuction-with-uipagecontrol)