# Page indication is missing in UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, ios7, uipageviewcontroller

I would like to utilise `UIPageViewController` to paginate through my datasource.
Essentially it works, however I don't get to see the dots as an indication on which page I am.

Someone has asked this question before and I have done exactly what [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14015836/92153) suggested.  However I still don't get any dots on the bottom of my screen.

Essentially I am using `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll` and navigation orientation is `UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal`.

I have created a [sample project](https://github.com/houmie/UIPageViewController) on GitHub to demonstrate the problem.

If anyone would be so kind and help out.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Update:**
Please see the answer by @Senseful below. It is preferred over this one.

**Original Answer:**
I checked out your project, and the reason you can't see the `UIPageController` (the dots) is because its default color is white, and the `UIPageViewController`'s view's superview is white. To solve this you could change the color of the background or change the color of the `UIPageController`.

To change the background color to a non-white color, in `-viewDidLoad:` in `FTAdviceViewController.m` the set the background color of the view that contains the `UIPageViewController`'s view.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    ...
}
```

To change the color of the dots, get the `UIPageViewController`'s `UIPageControl` subview after you've created the `UIPageViewController`. You can then alter its `pageIndicatorTintColor`, `currentPageIndicatorTintColor`, and `backgroundColor` properties.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ...
    // after creating the UIPageViewController
    for (UIView *subview in self.pageController.view.subviews) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIPageControl class]]) {
            UIPageControl *pageControl = (UIPageControl *)subview;
            pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
            pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
            pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Joseph. I didn't expect it to be in white colour. Considering iOS 7 is by default white with blue tint, its crazy that they chose the white colour for `UIPageControl`.

Comment: My pleasure :) This had me boggled too when I first encountered it.

Comment: OMG how dumb do I feel?  Thanks for this, it saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 39):

Another way to fix this issue is to [customize the page control's tint colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466718/can-we-customize-the-page-indicator-in-uipageviewcontroller):

```
UIPageControl *pageControlAppearance = [UIPageControl appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIPageViewController class], nil];
pageControlAppearance.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
pageControlAppearance.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

I answered a previous SO question with this block I used in my own Swift 4 project.

```
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    for view in self.view.subviews{
        if view is UIPageControl{
            (view as! UIPageControl).currentPageIndicatorTintColor = .yellow
            }
        }
    }
```

You have the UIPageControl in this block, so you can customize it as much as you want.