# How to get current view controller in page view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I want to get the current view controller at present in page view controller. how it can be done. Does it have some delegate to call or what.

Comment: Maybe this can help



http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400870/uipageviewcontroller-return-the-current-visible-view

Answer (score 25):

I just had the same problem. Looks like the current controller is last in the list after you did change the page. This worked for me, but I don't know if it's always true.

```
- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished previousViewControllers:(NSArray *)previousViewControllers transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed
{
    UIViewController *vc = [pageViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
}
```

Comment: @mnl what is failing? This worked for me, so if there's a bug I'd like to know =)

Comment: This will work if I have go to another view than the beginning one and that's when that delegate is called, other than that the delegate will not help , If I have made no navigation at all

Comment: For this to work, you need to add UIPageViewControllerDelegate to your header file and also set the delegate with something like this in viewDidLoad:
    self.pageViewController.delegate=self;

Answer (score 2):

Try get the first view controller in **pageViewController.viewControllers**

```
    if let vc = pageViewController.viewControllers?[0] {
        ... vc is current controller...
    }
```

If you want to handle page changes, do it in a delegate method:

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
    if let vc = pageViewController.viewControllers?[0] {
        ... vc is current controller...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are in any UIView class (as UIButton, UITable or any other subclass) that is a subView of the UIViewController.view (or of any subView.subView.subView... of it)

you can check if there's a UIViewController in the superVew(s) chain, and stop when you find a UIViewController

something like this:

```
UIViewController* controllerFound = nil;
for (UIView* next = [self superview]; next; next = next.superview) {
    UIResponder* nextResponder = [next nextResponder];
    if ([nextResponder isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]]) {
        controllerFound = (UIViewController*)nextResponder;
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't know this as i have not used this method. i need to find out in page view controller can you post anything related to that.