# Disable swiping/scrolling on the sides of PageViewController

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I'm working on creating an introduction page for the app with a few pages. I'm using UIPageViewController to do that.

Is there any way to disable bounce effect/scrolling on the sides of the first page (to the left) and the last page (to the right)? I would like it to stay fixed at those pages without being able to swipe to the sides where there is no content. Maybe I need to do it some other way?

**UPD:** I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795883/disable-bounce-effect-in-uipageviewcontroller), but it was pointed out to me that it's not the best way to do it.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no documented way to do this; the techniques in the link you posted are probably your best bet.

Answer (score -1):

Setting `bounces` to `NO` should do the trick.

Comment: What is this `bounces` property part of?

Comment: Through this swipe will disable . Do you have any other solution ?