# How to prevent PageViewController to overflow?

Tags: ios, objective-c, gesture, uipageviewcontroller

I am currently developing an `iOS` project that is based in a `Page View Controller`. Everything works fine, however, I would like to prevent the user to go beyond the limits of the pages.

In example, when the `PageViewController` is positioned in the first page, if the user tries to go to the previous page (even thought there is no one) by dragging the `Page View` to the left, the `Root View Controller` appears until the drag is released, as you can see in the screenshot below.

[image]

Is there any way to block this gesture in the first and the last page of the `Page View Controller`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795883/disable-bounce-effect-in-uipageviewcontroller

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21798218/disable-uipageviewcontroller-bounce

Comment: have a look at these answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `PageviewController` delegate method

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

if (indexTest < NUM_OF_PAGES) {
    switch (indexTest) {

        case 0:{
            NSLog(@"Page AFTER is Page: %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] ] );
            indexTest++;
            return [viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
            break;
        }
        case 1:{
            NSLog(@"Page AFTER is Page: %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[viewControllers objectAtIndex:2] ] );
            indexTest++;
            return [viewControllers objectAtIndex:2];
            break;
        }
        case 2:{
            NSLog(@"No pages AFTER this current page %d", indexTest);
            break;
        }
        default:{
            NSLog(@"PROBLEM  in viewAFTER, indexTest = %d!!!!", indexTest);
            break;
        }
    }

}
return nil;
```

}

do something like this , with `indexTest` is the int variable which increase the page count as per the swipe.

```
NUM_OF_PAGES is the total pages available for page controlling.
```