# No bouncing on UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

How do I not allow UIPageViewController to bounce? I would not like to allow the user to drag past the boundaries.

Comment: Isn't there an option for this in the properties inspector in the interface builder?

Comment: What's the option called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can't be done without hacks. See this question: [Disable bounce effect in UIPageViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795883/disable-bounce-effect-in-uipageviewcontroller)

On the few occassions I've needed to disable the bounce, I've just put all of my views in a `UIScrollView` and turned off `bounces`, instead of using `UIPageViewController`

Comment: Yeah I'm thinking about doing this. Just hope paging for UIScrollView isn't as a painful setup as UIPageViewController

Comment: And it's not! Very nice paging enabled!

Comment: I ran into this as well.  Here is a solid tutorial I found on YouTube to use UIScrollView for the same ends: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1_daE3IL_1s