# How To Scroll the line between the buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to scroll the line (uiview - Hieght=1) between the button And i had put the button in container view of pageviewcontroller.Pageviewcontroller is starting from bottom of the buttons .I want the line to move when i scroll pageviewcontrollers subviews.
The Image as shown below...
[image]

So this line white line I want to move when I scroll page 1 to 2 then 2 - 1 How can i do this Please help....
As I have to use pageviewcontroller

Comment: You can simply put a uiview and animate it using constriaints when you swipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this in with help of `UIScrollView` , in here no need of `UIpageViewController`

take the delegate methods of

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate;
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender;
```

**Step-1**

create the one scrollView like `self.tblScroll`

```
//It call end of scroll

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
if (scrollView != MovemylineinBlack && scrollView != MovemylineinRed)
{
    int x=fmod(scrollView.contentOffset.x, self.tblScroll.frame.size.width);
    if (x <= self.tblScroll.frame.size.width/2 )
    {
        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x-x, scrollView.contentOffset.y) animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x+self.tblScroll.frame.size.width-x, scrollView.contentOffset.y) animated:YES];
    }
   }
}
```

**Step-2**

// it s call your scroll is closusre

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate: (BOOL)decelerate
{
if (scrollView != MovemylineinBlack && scrollView != MovemylineinRed)
{
    int x=fmod(scrollView.contentOffset.x, self.tblScroll.frame.size.width);
    if (x <= self.tblScroll.frame.size.width/2 )
    {
        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x-x, scrollView.contentOffset.y) animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x+self.tblScroll.frame.size.width-x, scrollView.contentOffset.y) animated:YES];
    }
   }
 }
```

**Step-3**

// Imeplement the every drag of move capture method

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender
{
  if (self.tblScroll.contentOffset.x<KAPPDeviceWidth/2) // KAPPDeviceWidth--> this is your view Width
{
    self.viewSubBack.frame=CGRectMake(self.tblScroll.contentOffset.x, 106, 160, 5); // viewSubBack --> is your white line
}
else
{
    self.viewSubBack.frame=CGRectMake((KAPPDeviceWidth/2)+1, 106, 160, 5);
}
}
```

Comment: see this link once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795883/disable-bounce-effect-in-uipageviewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

This project will let you integrate this need
 https://github.com/hightower/HTHorizontalSelectionList

Comment: Since there are sourcecode available you may use it straight away.. Its one of the great implementation

Comment: But When I scroll between the pages in pageviewcontroller did the line will scroll between the buttons accordingly...??

Comment: Yeah with - (void)setSelectedButtonIndex:(NSInteger)selectedButtonIndex animated:(BOOL)animated;
 it will happen