# UIPageViewController didFinishAnimating claims to show a different view

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `UIPageViewController` that only ever has two `UIViewControllers` in. There is a `UISegmentControl` above the `UIPageViewController` that changes between the segments "new" and "hot" depending on which page the `UIPageViewController` is on. This works about 90% of the time, however, if I swipe as indicated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795883/disable-bounce-effect-in-uipageviewcontroller) question, the `UIPageViewController` gets confused on which page it is on. This results in the `UISegmentControl` saying "new" when actually the "hot" page is being displayed.

Each view controller is assigned a page index (0 or 1) when it's first instantiated. Then the following code changes the segmented control index:

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
    if completed,
        let index = (pageViewController.viewControllers?.last as? MyCollectionViewController)?.pageIndex,
        let pageType = PageType(rawValue: index) {
            currentPage = pageType
            segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = index
    }
}
```

What's weird is that when the bug is occurring, I print out the `pageIndex` of the `pageViewControllers` last `viewController` and it agrees with the segmentedControl index. Yet on screen, it is 100% not the viewController it's claiming is being shown...