# UIPageViewController don't move when there's no more pages?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a UIPageViewController and it works great. I can move all the pages. The thing is when Its at the first page and the last page and I try to drag more, the UIPageViewController bounce a little. I don't want this. How can I do this?

How it looks now:

http://s23.postimg.org/r4ud9y76z/Screen_Shot_2557_08_24_at_10_55_28_AM.png

How I want it to look like when no more pages when dragging:

http://s17.postimg.org/7w2mqb2f3/Screen_Shot_2557_08_24_at_10_55_36_AM.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable bounce effect in `UIPageViewController`:

```
for (UIView *view in self.pageViewController.view.subviews ) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
            UIScrollView *scroll = (UIScrollView *)view;
            scroll.bounces = NO;
        }
}
```

Comment: This disables pan gestures too. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21798218/disable-uipageviewcontroller-bounce