# UIPageViewController with dynamic content in childViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I have a UIPageViewController which has three childViewControllers. Those childViewControllers are disyplaying charts with are automatically updated each 5 seconds with dynamic data feteched from a network connection.

How do I automatically refresh the content of the childViewControllers inside the UIPageViewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the timer in the viewDidLoad, e.g. :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0f target:self selector:@selector(refreshControllers) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    //..
}

- (void)refreshControllers {
    //perform refreshing
    //when you got your _view1, _view2 etc..
    NSArray *viewControllers = @[_view1, _view2, _view3];
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how would i refresh the controllers inside the refreshControllers method?    eq. i have three childViewControllers in UIPopoverViewController lets call them  _view1, _view2, _view3. Now i have updated _view1 with new data, but how do i force the UIPopoverViewcontroller to reload its childViews?

Comment: Check my edited version, watchout for self.pageViewController, because if you actually are in your pageviewcontroller you would use only self.

Comment: Thank you very much, works great so far only one little issue left. I do call  setViewControllers:_firstVc,  addChildViewController_secondVc, addChildViewController:_thirdVc which updates the VCs now. But when the user moves the pageconrolview to the _secondVc, after the refresh is triggered the pageControl will move automatically back to _firstVc after the next refresh.  Is there anything i can do to keep the currently displayed vc displayed even if the vc's did refresh?

Comment: You'll need to keep track of the current view controller: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400870/uipageviewcontroller-return-the-current-visible-view