# UIPageViewControler get current number page from didFinishAnimating method?

Tags: objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

There is some way to bring from this method the current page I am in ?

```
-(void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pvc didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished previousViewControllers:(NSArray *)previousViewControllers transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed –
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIPageViewController: return the current visible view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400870/uipageviewcontroller-return-the-current-visible-view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is works for Me , thanks to Krumelur !

```
- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished previousViewControllers:(NSArray *)previousViewControllers transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed 
{
   if (completed) {
    int currentIndex = ((UIViewController *)[self.pageViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]).view.tag;
    self.pageControl.currentPage = currentIndex;
     }
  }
```