# How to get page index value into UIPageviewcontrller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I have created `UIPageviewcontroller` within multiple viewcontroller, Now I need to get `page index` value and `viewcontroller` name Into `mainviewcontroller` class using objective c.

`FYI :` I have created `UIPageviewcontroller` with multiple view controller via `Storyboard`.

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSString *vcRestorationID = viewController.restorationIdentifier;
    NSUInteger index = [self.contentPageRestorationIDs indexOfObject:vcRestorationID];

    if (index == self.contentPageRestorationIDs.count - 1) {

        return nil;
    }

    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index + 1];
}
```

Comment: index value of what? current view controller ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIPageViewController: return the current visible view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400870/uipageviewcontroller-return-the-current-visible-view)

Comment: Whenever swipe the page viewcontroller. I need to get which page I am using Its should work forward and reverse process also like eg: 1 2 3 then 3 2 1. @Mr.T