# How do I remove goBack events on UIButtons in UIPageViewControllers?

Tags: ios, uibutton, uipageviewcontroller

In an XCode project (iOS 5.1) where I have been using `UIPageViewController`, I noticed that when I tap on any button the automatic action is to send the `goBack`event and flip the page back to the previous index.

I am bewildered by this because checking on the responders for the `UIButton` they haven't been associated to the `goBack` event or any other event for that matter.

Any clues on how to remove this behavior?

Comment: what is the goBack event, please post some code

Comment: There's actually no code involved as this is purely on storyboards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after more searching I realized what really is happening.

Apparently the `UIButton` isn't throwing the goBack event; since the button is in the left field of the `UIPageViewController` subview a `UITapGesture` is captured on that region and initiates the `goBack` event.

The same thing will happen if a `UIButton` is on the right side of the `UIPageViewController`, which will cause a `goForward` event instead.

The details on how to fix this problem is in this question: [UIPageViewController Gesture recognizers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788780/uipageviewcontroller-gesture-recognizers)