# UIPageViewController Traps All UITapGestureRecognizer Events

Tags: objective-c, uiview, addsubview, uipageviewcontroller, uitapgesturerecognizer

It's been a long day at the keyboard so I'm reaching out :-)

I have a `UIPageViewController` in a typical implementation that basically follows Apple's standard template. I am trying to add an overlay that will allow the user to do things like touch a button to jump to certain pages or dismiss the view controller to go to another part of the app.

My problem is that the `UIPageViewController` is trapping all events from my overlay subview and I am struggling to find a workable solution.

Here's some code to help the example...

**In viewDidLoad**

```
// Page creation, pageViewController creation etc....

self.pageViewController.delegate = self;

[self.pageViewController setViewControllers:pagesArray
                                  direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                                   animated:NO
                                completion:NULL];

self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;

[self addChildViewController:self.pageViewController];
[self.view addSubview:self.pageViewController.view];

// self.overlay being the overlay view

if (!self.overlay) 
{
   self.overlay = [[MyOverlayClass alloc] init];  // Gets frame etc from class init
   [self.view addSubview:self.overlay];
}
```

This all works great. The overlay gets created, it gets show over the top of the pages of the `UIPageViewController` as you would expect. When pages flip, they flip underneath the overlay - again just as you would expect.

However, the `UIButtons` within the `self.overlay` view never get the tap events. The `UIPageViewController` responds to all events.

I have tried overriding `-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch` per the suggestions here without success.

[UIPageViewController Gesture recognizers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788780/uipageviewcontroller-gesture-recognizers)

I have tried manually trapping all events and handling them myself - doesn't work (and to be honest even if it did it would seem like a bit of a hack).

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to trap the events or maybe a better approach to using an overlay over the top of the `UIPageViewController`.

Any and all help very much appreciated!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to iterate through `UIPageViewController.GestureRecognizers` and assign `self` as a delegate for those gesture and implement

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch;
```

Your code may be like this:

In viewDidLoad

```
for (UIGestureRecognizer * gesRecog in self.pageViewController.gestureRecognizers)
{
        gesRecog.delegate = self;
}
```

And add the following method:

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    if (touch.view != self.pageViewController.view]
    {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: That worked Basem! Sorry I didn't get round to marking as the correct answer until just now!

Answer (score 0):

The documented way to prevent the `UIPageViewController` from scrolling is to not assign the `dataSource` property. If you assign the data source it will move into 'gesture-based' navigation mode which is what you're trying to prevent.

Without a data source you manually provide view controllers when you want to with `setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion` method and it will move between view controllers on demand.

The above can be deduced from [Apple's documentation of UIPageViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html) (Overview, second paragraph):

> To support gesture-based navigation, you must provide your view controllers using a data source object.