# UIPageViewController cancel Touchevents

Tags: xamarin.ios, uipageviewcontroller, touch-event

I am working at a App with the UIPageViewController. Everything works fine but i dont like that the page is changed with one touch on the left or right side. I know that i get the event with TouchesBegan, but how can i cancel this event?

Comment: See this answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788780/uipageviewcontroller-gesture-recognizers/10467686#10467686.